# Shell Script - Maximized Desktop Application in Linux

Tags: bash, shell, unix, desktop-application

I am a beginner in Unix environment or with desktop application.
I have application running and I am able to get its pid using this `pgrep <<pid name>>`. Can we maximize this this application or makes its window active using shell script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`wmctrl` does just that:

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=1234

# Note that one PID may have several windows opened, possibly 
# with the same title, so you may have to implement 
# some additional logic in order to choose the correct one.

window_refs=$(wmctrl -p -l | grep " $pid " | egrep -o 0x[0-9a-z]+)
for ref in $window_refs; do
    wmctrl -i -r "$ref" -b "add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz"
done
```

Comment: You should double quote variables to prevent globbing and word splitting.  Also consider using `$(..)` instead of legacy backticks.

Comment: It is working fine for the first time. When I am minimizing the window and running the script again, it does not show up. And I am getting this message `Cannot convert argument to number.`. Please explain what does it mean `grep "$pid"`.

Comment: @user3439894: seems that $window_refs shouldn't be double-quoted, as then it gets treated as a single string, breaking the loop. Removed the quotes once again.

Comment: @Vish: should be OK now, please re-try. The command works by listing all active windows first together with the respective PIDs, then filtering out only relevant ones, and finally creating a list of window references that are actually used for manipulating the windows.

Comment: @Vadim Landa, yes some variables shouldn't be double-quoted base on where/how used, as in this case in the `for .. in $..` however `.. -r "$ref"` should be.  Best to check code with [ShellCkeck](http://www.shellcheck.net).